# Sauna heater wiring from 3 prong to 4 prong

Tags: dryer, wire, heater

30 amp sauna heater that I need to wire. I plan on using my dryer outlet which is 4 prong but my sauna heater is 3 prong if I'm not mistaken as it has "L1, L2, ground."

My question is could I purchase an 8/3 and just cap off the neutral on both sides?

I plan to run the cord about 25 feet from the heater to the dryer outlet.

I plan on buying a NEMA 14-30P but capping off both ends of the wire. Is this okay or is better to just electrical tape it?

Answer (score 2):

Connect the neutral to the plug if using 8/3 cord. Put a wirenut (and tape - this is one place where taping a wirenut is reasonable) on the unused wire at the heater end of the cord.

IMHO it's also perfectly reasonable to use an 8/2 cord and leave the neutral prong disconnected, since the appliance does not need neutral, but if you are using 8/3, connect it to the plug.

Comment: I believe when specifying cord the ground is counted and not assumed like with romex. So the OP would need 8/3, which would be a black, red and insulated green ground.+

Answer (score 1):

### Can't use Romex for extension cord!!

Romex (NM-B and UF-B) are made for wiring in the walls, that never moves.  You may have noticed it is very stiff.  That means it is solid or coarse stranded wire, and will not bend well.  Instead of bending, it will metal-fatigue and strands will break.  At that point it starts a fire from overheat or arcing.

You need a special type of cable called **cordage**.  You're familiar with cordage; it's on every appliance.  Note how it is flexible and tough.   It has dozens of strands, like welding cable.

### Cordage is a little different

Now, cordage is numbered differently.  When we say /3 Romex, we really mean 4 wires.  With cordage, /3 means 3 wires and one will be green ground.   That's the stuff to use.

You only need #10 cordage since you are carrying <30A.  There are a variety of cordage markings, such as SJOW or SJOOW.  Skip the home store, go straight to the electrical supply house, both for the cordage, and also for the plugs and sockets that will go onto the cordage.

You won't like the price of #10 cordage, but you wouldn't have liked the price of #8 NM-B either.

It's perfectly legit to build an extension cord with 10/3 SJOOW cordage, a NEMA 14-30 *plug* on one end, and a NEMA 6-30 *socket* on the other.  In these large sizes, most extension cords are home-built ("field assembled").

You use the white wire in the cordage for the other (red) hot.  Pay close attention to the strain relief where the sheath (outer coating) is clamped into the plug. It needs to hold well.